# responsive design for websites using css

Tags: css

I am writting css for some websites which must be responsive. I am new to css and dont know much of the responsive techniques. I have divided my css code into three parts.

1. Desktop : all universal styles
2. Tablets : @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) { my styles }
3. Mobiles : @media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) { my styles }

Will it be fully responsive and support ***All*** standard devices or do i have to make few more changes? Here **ALL** means literally all devices.

Comment: what about for the width in b/w 481px and 766px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to not leave spaces between 481 and 766 and between 0 to 319 px.
That is not really responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:480px){ // styles for mobile}
@media screen and (max-device-width:780px){ // styles for tablets}
@media screen and (min-device-width:781px){ // styles for desktop}
```

**EDIT** There are wearables lower than 319 px. Example:

```
/* ----------- Moto 360 Watch ----------- */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

There should be there some devices between 481 and 766.

Comment: Is there any standard device having width from 0 to 319 and 481 to 766.

Answer (score 3):

*If you think responsive's simple, I feel bad for you son. We got 99 viewports, but the iPhone's just one.*

Here is the list of [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Yes i know, that's why i am here. Does it mean that i'v to write same code  9 times for ipads, 3 times for galaxy tablets, 3 times for nexus tablets and i dont know how many times for different mobiles? Please explain.

Comment: @AdityaKumar you don't have to use all of them, it is just a way to target different devices more specifically. Start with general media queries, then work your way up.

Answer (score 1):

What almost everyone got wrong is that responsive design should be done based on some predefined breakpoints. It should define your content, not your visitor's screen. If there are 10 breakpoints, there is something definitely wrong with the site structure. Less media queries = better. Start from there and conclude the perfect structure for your content for ANY screen.

Comment: I think this is the best reference which i have got. 
[link](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)
Might help others too